# setGraphic() not working correctly on recursively created TreeItems

Tags: java, recursion, javafx, treeview, assign

I'm writing a folder synchronization app. Currently, I'm working on the part responsible for recursively going through the two user-specified directory structures, comparing the folders and files in them to the other structure, and displaying whether each file or folder is unchanged, changed, or new, by means of a colored dot. The problem is that the program in its current state, while evaluating the relation correctly, only displays the dot on *one* TreeItem per dot color instead on all of them. Pic for reference:
[image]

Whats causing this? I have a suspicion that it has to do with the way object assignment works in Java, so I'm reassigning one and the same object somehow to all the proper TreeItems, only stopping at the last one, but that's too broad to work with. See the offending function below.

```
private void compareAndFillInSourceTreeView(Path x, TreeItem root) throws IOException {
    String xSourceName = x.getName(x.getNameCount() - 1).toString();
    String xTargetName = (getEquivalentFileInTarget(x).getName(getEquivalentFileInTarget(x).getNameCount() - 1))
            .toString();

    System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("NEW CALL: " + x.toString() + " " + root);
    System.out.println("EQUIVALENT: " + getEquivalentFileInTarget(x) + " EXISTS: " +
            getEquivalentFileInTarget(x).toFile().exists());
    System.out.println("IS NEW: " + xTargetName + ", " + (xTargetName == null));
    System.out.println("UNCHANGED: " + x + " " + getEquivalentFileInTarget(x) + " NAMES: " + xSourceName + ", "
            + xTargetName);
    System.out.println("CHANGED: " + ((x.getName(x.getNameCount() - 1)) ==
            getEquivalentFileInTarget(x).getName(getEquivalentFileInTarget(x).getNameCount() - 1)));

    if (x.toFile().isFile()) {
        System.out.println("THIS IS A FILE: " + x.toString());

        //if new, i.e. doesn't exist in the target
        if (!getEquivalentFileInTarget(x).toFile().exists()) {
            System.out.println("EQUIVALENT DOESN'T EXIST FOR THIS FILE IN TARGET");
            TreeItem newBranch = makeBranch(xSourceName, root);
            newBranch.setGraphic(blueDotIcon);
        }

        //if unchanged
        else if (sameContents(x, getEquivalentFileInTarget(x)) && (xSourceName.equals(xTargetName))) {
            System.out.println("THIS FILE AND ITS EQUIVALENT ARE EQUAL");
            TreeItem newBranch = makeBranch(x.getName(x.getNameCount() - 1).toString(), root);
            newBranch.setGraphic(greenDotIcon);
        }

        //if same name, but different contents, i.e. changed
        else if ((x.getName(x.getNameCount() - 1)).equals(
                getEquivalentFileInTarget(x).getName(getEquivalentFileInTarget(x).getNameCount() - 1))) {
            TreeItem newBranch = makeBranch(x.getName(x.getNameCount() - 1).toString(), root);
            newBranch.setGraphic(yellowDotIcon);

        } else {
            System.out.println("BAD, putInTreeView() Error, it should never reach this line");
            System.out.println("Error log: " + x + ", " + getEquivalentFileInTarget(x));
        }

    } else if (x.toFile().isDirectory()){ //if it's a folder, checked explicitly because it's behaving weird
        System.out.println("THIS IS A DIRECTORY: " + x.toString());

        if (getEquivalentFileInTarget(x).toFile().exists()) {
            System.out.println("EQUIVALENT EXISTS FOR THIS DIRECTORY IN TARGET.");
            //make new branches and mark them as existing folders
            TreeItem currentSourceTreeViewRoot = makeBranch(x.getName(x.getNameCount() - 1).toString(), root);
            currentSourceTreeViewRoot.setExpanded(true);
            currentSourceTreeViewRoot.setGraphic(greenDotIcon);
            for (File i : x.toFile().listFiles()) {
                System.out.println("Rec. called for: " + currentSourceTreeViewRoot);
                compareAndFillInSourceTreeView(i.toPath(), currentSourceTreeViewRoot);
            }

        } else {
            System.out.println("EQUIVALENT DOESN'T EXIST FOR THIS DIRECTORY IN TARGET.");
            //if they don't exist, make the branches anyway and mark them as representing nonexistent folders
            TreeItem currentSourceTreeViewRoot = makeBranch((x.getName(x.getNameCount() - 1)).toString(), root);
            currentSourceTreeViewRoot.setExpanded(true);

            for (File i : x.toFile().listFiles()) {
                System.out.println("Rec. called for: " + currentSourceTreeViewRoot);
                compareAndFillInSourceTreeView(i.toPath(), currentSourceTreeViewRoot);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Related question / possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27696414/javafx-why-does-adding-a-node-to-a-pane-multiple-times-or-to-different-panes-r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption is correct. When assigning a graphic with `setGraphic` you are telling JavaFX where in the scene graph to locate this node. When you call `setGraphic` again with the same object as parameter you are effectively moving it to a different place in the scene graph.

Create a new dot/circle for every item and your problem should be solved.